# How to fix sql injection in order rails query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-injection

Im new to ruby and followed [this](https://www.cloudsecuretech.com/how-to-fix-the-sql-injection-vulnerability-in-ruby-on-rails/) blog  to fix sql injection bug but my query is giving error .

**Original query :**

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_one :Driver, lambda {
     where(status: PASSENGER_STATUS, connected_number: [phone, mobile])
    .order("FIELD (`classDummy`.`status`, #{PASSENGER_STATUS.join(', ')}")
  }, class_name: :classDummy
```

Whereas , PASSENGER_STATUS is ( in other class )

```
PASSENGER_STATUS = [
  'employed','temporary'
  ].freeze
```

**SQL INJECTION fix I did**

```
  order("FIELD (`classDummy`.`status`, ? )", PASSENGER_STATUS.join(', '))
```

But this is throwing exception while executing query.

Exception that Im getting :

> **ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
> server version for the right syntax to use near '?,**

Comment: what exception?

Comment: @Geoffroy : Added exception in question itself .

Answer (score 4):

As Geoffroy already pointed out, in your specific example there is no risk for a SQL injection because the input data is under your control.

But nevertheless, you can find the [`sanitize_sql_for_order`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Sanitization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-sanitize_sql_for_order) in the Rails Docs. And the example from the documentation matches exactly your use-case:

> `sanitize_sql_for_order(condition)`
>
> Accepts an array, or string of SQL conditions and sanitizes them into a valid SQL fragment for an ORDER clause.
>
> ```
> sanitize_sql_for_order(["field(id, ?)", [1,3,2]])
> # => "field(id, 1,3,2)"
>
> sanitize_sql_for_order("id ASC")
> # => "id ASC"
> ```

Using this method you can write your association like this:

```
has_one :Driver, lambda {
     where(status: PASSENGER_STATUS, connected_number: [phone, mobile])
       .order(sanitize_sql_for_order(["FIELD(`classDummy`.`status`, ?)", PASSENGER_STATUS])
}, class_name: :classDummy
```

Answer (score 1):

The blog your read is about handling user input, in which case it's really important to prevent sql injecton.

In:

```rb
order("FIELD (`classDummy`.`status`, #{PASSENGER_STATUS.join(', ')})")
```

You are injection code in the SQL query but it's code you control and know precisely what it is, so there's no risk of SQL injection.

Now about your problem, `order` does not replace the parameter `?` while generating the query, it simply does not work like `where`.

In other words: use the code you were using before, it worked perfectly fine and is not subject to SQL injection (as long as you control what `PASSENGER_STATUS` is)

Check the logs to see the SQL query sent to the server, you'll understand better what's going on

Comment: Thanks for your answer .  I will try to change my query .